# Laravel- file_put_contents()-failed to open stream, permission denied

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am facing below error, which is very random in occurrence.

```
file_put_contents(C:\projectname\storage\framework/cache/data/a4/4d/a44d6gn6d8d90gh32bf2999bbghfe):failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I googled a lot about this problem, even after trying some solutions this problem still persists. I have tried by clearing cache (`php artisan cache:clear`), and also by giving recursive write permission to the cache folder.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED!!**

*In my case the issue was due to multiple users on the server, It was solved by giving the recursive writable permissions for storage folder to all the users on the server machine. Its good if it helps someone!! :-)*

Comment: try right click on storage folder and properties there on security you should enable allow write permission for you

Comment: Thanks For your response @Sebastian , I have tried by giving write permission to storage folder, It also did not solve the issue.

Comment: file_put_contents(C:\projectname\storage\framework/cache/data/a4/4d/a44d6gn6d8d90gh32bf2999bbghfe), please see the pattern of forward and backward slashes. It may be something wrong there.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Ramesh KC, In my case the issue was due to multiple users on the server, It was solved by giving the recursive writable permissions for storage folder to all the users on the server machine. Thanks for your response :-) !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my windows 10. After trying so many things, I finally nailed the problem. It was avast antivirus blocking apache from writing to my documents folder. Disable antivirus for a moment and see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @ekene, In my case the issue was due to multiple users on the server, It was solved by giving the recursive writable permissions for storage folder to all the users on the server machine. Thanks for your response :-) !!